# input string as character array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have search a lot but i haven't find my answer
I want to write a program that will give an array with 3 members
and then i want to print array with 3 members :

```
char array[3] ;  
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){ 
 cin>>array[i] ;}
```

But the point is , i don't want to cin array members in character ,and i want this in string ;
but the another point is i don't want to use `#include <string.h>`
what i have to do ?
I want to give input array from user in this form:

```
char array[3]={"input1","input2","input3"} 
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
  cin>>array[i] ; 
 }
 cout<<array[0]<<" "<<array[1]<<" "<<array[2] ; 
  //output = input1   input2   input3
```

Comment: What do you want to take as input a char or a string?

Comment: i want to declare a char array BUT  with string members @Tushar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char array[3][10];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cin >> array[i];
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

Where the 2nd size of the array depends on the length of the input string.

Answer (score 1):

char array[n] will only store n characters; use char array[n][m].  Remember, a c string (char[]) is different than string.  In your case, you would want `char array[3][length]' where length is the max space to 'reserve' for each word.

```
char array[3][32];              //you wont need to fill this with data right away

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    std::cin >> array[i];
}

std::cout << " " << array[0] << " " << array[1] << " " << array[2];
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the answer. Please consider it moving to the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hope This Solves!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char arr[3][100]; // Declaring the two dimensional character array 3 denotes number of inputs whereas 100 dentoes the length.
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
           cin>>arr[i];
   }
  for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
       cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
  }
    return 0;
}
```